# Multiple inheritance and interface methods

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

For several graphic objects I inherit from `QGraphicsLineItem`, `QGraphicsRectItem` and so on.

```
class CustomLine : public QGraphicsLineItem{};

class CustomRect : public QGraphicsRectItem{};
```

Those objects are added to a container, a custom subclass of a `QGraphicsScene "scene"` that is meant for displaying and interacting with those items. `this->scene->items()` returns a list of `QGraphicItem`'s: `QList<QGraphicsItem* >`

What I want to do is each custom object class to have the same custom interface methods, for example `setModeX()`. Then I could do stuff like:

```
Foreach (BaseItem *item, this->scene->items()){
    item->setModeX(...);
}
```

But how do I achieve that? 
If I make an interface like

```
class BaseItem{
    public: setModeX(); [...]
    private: Mode mode_;
}
```

and inherit

```
class CustomLine : public QGraphicsLineItem, BaseItem {};
```

So while the scene should only contain items based on `BaseItem` (not sure if this is really needed for this task), I first retrieve a list of objects of one of its 2 base classes, namely `QGraphicsItem`, and need to cast it to its other base class `BaseItem` to use the interface methods.
I will probably not be able to cast a CustomLine-item to BaseItem in the loop above, because it does not know about the other base class.

EDIT:

- I use MinGW 4.8 32 bit (g++).
- I noticed that when I start the foreach-loop, the items in my scene disappear (yet don't see the reason why)

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to do the cast? If the loop only cares about the behavior provided by `BaseItem`, then it should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, I mean a `QGraphicsScene`. It is meant for displaying `QGraphicsItems`.

Comment: It says `cannot convert 'QGraphicsItem* const' to 'BaseItem*' in initialization`

Comment: It's because `QGraphicsItem*` is not a `CustomLine*`. Your scene has to a collection of `BaseItem*s` or `CustomLine*`s.

Comment: Please make it more clear in your question that a `scene` is a `QGraphicsScene`, which is a container of `QGraphicsItem`s, and that you want to convert each `QGraphicsItem` into a `BaseItem`.

Comment: I added the info as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `scene` is a `QGraphicsScene`, it only consists of `QGraphicsItem`s. So you cannot directly iterate over `scene` as `BaseItem`s as you show in your code. You have to iterate over each `QGraphicsItem`. You describe that you could downcast to your `CustomLine` and then upcast back to a `BaseItem`, but this only works if you know that all the items in the `scene` are lines. If `scene` contains other types of items, your technique would require you to iterate of each kind of item until you found a downcast that worked, and then cast it back to `BaseItem`.

```
QGraphicsItem
          \         BaseItem
QGraphicsLineItem   /
            \      /
            CustomLine
```

A simple solution would have been available to you if the Qt library had used virtual inheritance on `QGraphicsItem`. Then, you would simply need to use virtual inheritance on `QGraphicsItem` from `BaseItem`, and then down casting would have worked.

```
           QGraphicsItem
            /        \
QGraphicsLineItem   BaseItem
            \        /
           CustomLineItem
```

Since Qt does not do so, you would either need to make custom changes to the Qt library, or code in your own conversion mechanism.

Assuming you are unwilling to make custom modifications to the Qt library itself, then one approach is to create a mapping between Qt's `QGraphicsItem` and your `BaseItem`. The mapping can be done within the constructor of your `BaseItem`, and undone from `BaseItem`s destructor. To make undoing the mapping more efficient, you can also create a link from the `BaseItem` to the `QGraphicsItem`.

```
class BaseItem {
    static std::unordered_map<QGraphicsItem *, BaseItem *> map;
    QGraphicsItem *link_;
public:
    BaseItem (QGraphicsItem *q) : link_(q) {
        //...
        map[q] = this;
    }
    virtual ~BaseItem () {
       map.erase(link_);
       //...
    }
    static BaseItem * getBaseItem (QGraphicsItem *q) {
        std::unordered_map<QGraphicsItem *, BaseItem *>::iterator i;
        if ((i = map.find(q)) == map.end()) return NULL;
        return i->second;
    }
    //...
};

//...
std::unordered_map<QGraphicsItem *, BaseItem *> BaseItem::map;
```

In your derived classes, you would simply need to pass `this` to the `BaseItem` constructor.

```
class CustomLine : public QGraphicsLineItem, public BaseItem {
public:
    CustomLine () : BaseItem(this) {
        //...
    };
    //...
};
```

And then your loop would use the static `BaseItem::getBaseItem()` function to convert from a `QGraphicsItem` pointer to a `BaseItem` pointer. Thus, since there is no way to create a useable inheritance relationship between `QGraphicsItem` and `BaseItem`, their relationship is recorded in a table.

```
QGraphicsItem <-----------------. link
          \         BaseItem <--' map
QGraphicsLineItem   /
            \      /
            CustomLine
```

Comment: Is there also a similar alternative without C++11?
I would need to `#include <unordered_map>` which is experimental in QtCreator 3.0.x that I use.

Comment: You can use a `map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Should work just fine, but remember to declare the interface methods virtual in the base class, at least if you want polymorphic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the functions that you want to exist in every derived class as virtual in the base class. A function that is defined as virtual in the base class can give a default implementation, but derived classes are free to override that implementation and provide their own. You can also declare that function "purely virtual" which means derived classes MUST provide an implementation for that particular function.

In either case, when calling that function on an instantiated object pointed to by a pointer of the base class, it will notice that the base class declared the function to be virtual and use a virtual table (vtable) to find which function to call (As in the base class' definition of the function, if it exists, or the derived classes version of the function).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are some constraints on your problem that make this more of an issue than it should be. If you can't control the underlying pointers in your `scene`, but you know that each of those items inherits from `BaseItem`, then you can do a cast inside your for loop.

For instance, using the structure you have above:

```
Foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, this->scene){
    ((BaseItem*) item)->setModeX(...);
}
```

Of course, this is only if you can guarantee that the objects in your scene are derived from `BaseItem`.

Comment: Now it compiled, but crashed at execution. I tried `BaseItem *item_base = dynamic_cast<BaseItem*>(item);` in the foreach loop and checked  `item_base` for 0. It is 0 every time :/

Comment: A `dynamic_cast` only works if `QGraphicsItem` is a polymorphic class, which it seems it isn't.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the compiler that you're using? On mine (g++), the above compiles and works just fine even with a non-polymorphic `QGraphicsItem` stub class.

Comment: Try doing a `BaseItem* base = (BaseItem*) item;` and check if `base` points to a valid object.

Answer (score 0):

[CRTP](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to the rescue:

```
template <class D> class Base {
  D& m_d;
public:
  Base(D& derived) : m_d(d) { ... }
  ...
};

class CustomLine : public QGraphicsLine, Base<CustomLine> {
  ...
  CustomLine() : Base(*this) { ... }
};
```

Comment: I don't understand how I should use this, to be able to access `BaseItem` if I get a `QGraphicsLineItem` with `scene->items()`.

Comment: @user2366975 You can `dynamic_cast` to either `CustomLine` or `Base<CustomLine>`.